# Incompatible firebase libraries in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I am getting error with syncing gradle because of these lines

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'
```

I don't know why they are not compatible with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **extremely** old dependencies for Firebase.  You should upgrade everything so that they match what's in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  For FirebaseUI you should consult [its documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), and make sure the version you choose matches the other Firebase dependencies.